# Avoid multiple url_encode()

Tags: php, urlencode

how can I avoid multiple [url_encode](http://www.php.net/urlencode)?

```
echo urlencode('http://www.php.net/urlencode?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Furlencode')
```

output

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Furlencode%3Furl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.php.net%252Furlencode
```

expected result

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Furlencode%3Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Furlencode
```

Comment: i'm tempted to say "*by design*". Is checking for occurances of `%` and option? If they exist, it means you have an encoded url so you decode it to make sure you have the original and then encode it again to make sure parts that might not be encoded are encoded?

Comment: are you sure you do not want multiple (nested) url_encode? how should things work without that?

Comment: @AndreschSerj `urlencode( urldecode('URL') )` ?!

Comment: @sndesign Maybe? Result would be `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Furlencode%3Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Furlencode` right? Anbd that is what you asked for. Wild Guess: You are having an XY Problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are wanting to `urlencode` a URL for use in the query string (recursively/iterative), something like this:

```
$s = 'http://www.php.net/urlencode?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Furlencode';
//parse the url
$p = parse_url($s);
//check if there is a query string 
$q = isset($p['query']) ? $p['query'] : '';
//urlencode the main url and then append the already encoded query string
echo urlencode(str_replace($q, '', $s)) . $q;
```

Or possibly:

```
echo urlencode(urldecode($s));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
str_replace("%25","",urlencode('http://www.php.net/urlencode?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Furlencode'))
```